# there is no Window object in blank page in Chrome 16

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this simple script in my bookmark bar.

```
javascript:window.open("https://mybugs.com/show_bug.cgi?id="+window.prompt('bug number?'),'_blank')
```

I used it as a short link to one page which need a parameter. It worked well before. But it broken after I upgrade to Chrome 16. Looks like there is no Window object in a blank page.

How to handle this?

Comment: When you say a "blank page", do you mean the New Tab page, or about:blank? On my machine (Windows 7, Chrome 16.0.912), both of those pages have a DOMWindow object available (tested by opening the console and typing "window").

Comment: Actually, I just looked a bit further, and though the page might have a window object, other security measures stop the execution of address bar javascript. See my answer below for a link.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DOMWindow object (testable by creating a new tab, opening the console and typing "window"). However there has been a deliberate change in security policy recently, to:

> "Protect sensistive chrome: and chrome-extension: schemes as not being able to be manipulated by bookmarklets and javascript: URLs typed into the omnibox."

See http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=98849 for details.